# Thrift is failing to run on regionservers: getMaster attempts fail with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: hbase, thrift

I'm trying to get Thrift running on each regionserver (for mapreduce input as well as future load balancing).

Starting up the Thrift servers is failing, however, with `12/01/30 15:52:32 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 9 of 10 failed; no more retrying.`

There is a route to the host (pings succeed), hbase master is running on the default port (and is confirmed to be present using lsof -i :60000), but I'm still getting

```
12/01/30 15:52:32 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 9 of 10 failed; no more retrying.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:408)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:328)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:883)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:750)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC$Invoker.invoke(HBaseRPC.java:257)
        at $Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:419)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:360)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer$HBaseHandler.<init>(ThriftServer.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer$HBaseHandler.<init>(ThriftServer.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer.doMain(ThriftServer.java:870)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer.main(ThriftServer.java:927)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: master:60000
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer$HBaseHandler.<init>(ThriftServer.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer$HBaseHandler.<init>(ThriftServer.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer.doMain(ThriftServer.java:870)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer.main(ThriftServer.java:927)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on the hbase master machine you have a firewall issue or it is binding to the wrong network interface?
To ensure that this is not the case? I would try netcat nc, telnet or something like this from the exact same machine where you are installing thrift and see if they can connect to this host / port.

Comment: The regionserver running on the same node I'm trying to start thrift on can connect to the hmaster without trouble, and I'm able to ping, so there's connectivity.

Comment: strange. As a last resort, I would start a packet capture on the thriftserver machine and then start the ThriftServer (see wireshark, tshark). This will tell you exactly what is happening to cause the Connection refused error.